# Does anyone have a .ico with an image in PNG format?

Tags: png, ico

Windows supports icons in PNG format since Vista. You supposedly have the same format as a .ico file, but the image itself is a PNG, no BITMAPINFOHEADER.

Anyone has such an icon or a piece of software that can generate one?

Answer (score 5):

Take any PNG file and rename it with a .ico extension.  Really, that's all it is.

See also [The evolution of the ICO file format, part 4: PNG images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473).

Comment: Is it really so simple? What about multi-resolution icons?

Comment: Works for some image editors but not for others.

Answer (score 1):

[The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)
It's free and it can generate .ico files in all of its variations.
Just open the image, save it as .ico and a popup window asks you to choose the format.

Answer (score 1):

There are some websites which can convert PNG to ICO, like this one:
http://convertico.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use AveIconifier2

"Aveiconifier2 is designed as a drag-and-drop tool that converts ICO files to PNG files and vice versa."

"It can create multi-icons from 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64, 72x72 96x96, 128x128 PNG files. The application also supports batch conversion by simply dragging multiple ICO/PNG files to the program window."

[Download Link for AveIconifier2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/Multimedia/Graphics/Windows-Portable-Applications-Portable-AveIconifier.shtml)

Comment: Does not work at all.